# Get peace of number using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I´m trying to get a part of number using Regex in Python, I want to collect the sequence of numbers after 0 (zero) number, like this:

```
S_9900002127
S_9900000719
S_9900008012
```

So, in this example above I want to get: `2127, 719 and 8012`, and I have done the Regex:

```
r'(_9(\d*)[.^0](\d*))'
```

and get the second group of Regex: `[2]`, but the result is: `2127, 719 and 12`.

Look that the third one ignore the number `8` because the `0` (zero).

Could someone help me to get the correct result `2127, 719 and 8012` ???

Comment: Try `_9+0+([1-9]\d*)$` or `_9[1-9]+0*([1-9]\d*)$` and get Group 1.

Comment: Try /(?<=0)([1-9]\d+)/g

Comment: On these both ways that you inform, I can get only **8012**, I could not get the **2127 and 719**.

Comment: Works fine whit @Cooper method: ```/(?<=0)([1-9]\d+)/g```. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you only wish the strings that start with S_99 then `/(?<=S_99[0]+)([1-9]\d+)/g`

Comment: You just did not explain this example is a single multiline string. To make `$` match end of a line, you need `re.M` option.

Comment: What is to be returned if the string were  `'S_990608012'? Showing the desired result for a few examples is insufficient. Please edit to provide a statement of the rule for determining what is to be returned (in words). For example, "I wish to return the end of the string following the last two consecutive zeroes" or perhaps "I wish to return the end of the string following the last zero in the string" (though your last example seems to contradict that) or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
text = r"""S_9900002127
S_9900000719
S_9900008012"""
print( re.findall(r'0+([1-9]\d*)$', text, re.M) )
# => ['2127', '719', '8012']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2lSSIm) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X3XQfZ/1). *Details*:

- `0+` - one or more `0`s
- `([1-9]\d*)` - Group 1: a non-zero digit and then zero or more digits
- `$` - end of a line.